# Why is my ID (route value) null when uploading files that are too large?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, file-upload

I've got and API action that receives a file that needs to be stored and an ID of an already stored (in a database) object that contains the metadata of the file.

When I send a file below the size limit (60MB) both the `id` (which comes from the route) and `file` parameters contain a value. But when I send a file that is larger than the size limit both `file` *and* `id` are empty.

Now, I can understand the `file` parameter being empty, but why is the `id` value not available even though the route contains an `id` value (see attached images)?

(I need the ID to delete the metadata from the database in case the file upload fails)

```
    [HttpPut, Route("{id}/upload")]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 60000000, ValueLengthLimit = 60000000)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromRoute] string id, IFormFile file)
    {
        .... code ...

        return Ok();
    }
```

A file sent to the API that is within the limits:

[image]

A file sent to the API that is outside the limits (NOTE the `file` and `id` are both `null`):

[image]

Comment: It is by default.If you want to get Id,you can try to set a bigger value in `RequestFormLimits`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I know I can raise the limit. That is not the problem and also not the question. The question is _why_ I am not getting the ID even though it is present in the request. You say it is by default, does that mean I can configure it to act different? And can you point me to the docs thats says it is the default behaviour?